# ecryptfs-setup-private failing on Centos 6

Tags: centos, mount, security, disk-encryption, ecryptfs

```
$ ecryptfs-setup-private --force
Enter your login passphrase:
Enter your mount passphrase [leave blank to generate one]:

************************************************************************
YOU SHOULD RECORD YOUR MOUNT PASSPHRASE AND STORE IT IN A SAFE LOCATION.
  ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
THIS WILL BE REQUIRED IF YOU NEED TO RECOVER YOUR DATA AT A LATER TIME.
************************************************************************

Done configuring.

Testing mount/write/umount/read...
Inserted auth tok with sig [a27907c11868ebc7] into the user session keyring
Inserted auth tok with sig [5ca19d6c4edfa12f] into the user session keyring
mount: No such file or directory
ERROR:  Could not mount private ecryptfs directory
```

Any idea how to solve this? Checking ecryptfs-setup-private source code, this is where it's failing:

```
/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private || error "$(gettext 'Could not mount private ecryptfs directory')"
```

The file exists:

```
# which mount.ecryptfs_private
/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `mount.ecryptfs_private` call is failing, so it's not able to mount the eCryptfs folders it tried to set up.

I'm not sure why, but checking `man mount.ecryptfs_private` it reveals some info like:

> ```
>    mount.ecryptfs_private is a mount helper  utility  for  non-root  users  to
>    cryptographically mount a private directory, ~/Private by default.
>
>    This  program  optionally  takes one argument, ALIAS.  If ALIAS is omitted,
>    the program will default to using "Private" using:
>     - $HOME/.Private as the SOURCE
>     - $HOME/Private as the DESTINATION
>     - $HOME/.ecryptfs/Private.sig for the key signatures.
>
>    If ALIAS is specified, then the program will look  for  an  fstab(5)  style
>    configuration in:
>     - $HOME/.ecryptfs/ALIAS.conf and for key signature(s) in:
>     - $HOME/.ecryptfs/ALIAS.sig
>
>    The mounting will proceed if, and only if:
>      - the required passphrase is in their kernel keyring, and
>      - the current user owns both the SOURCE and DESTINATION mount points
>      - the DESTINATION is not already mounted
>
>    This program will:
>      - mount SOURCE onto DESTINATION
>      - as an ecryptfs filesystem
>      - using the AES cipher
>      - with a key length of 16 bytes
>      - using the passphrase whose signature is in ~/.ecryptfs/Private.sig
> ```

So check for something missing or wrong, look for files like:

- `$HOME/.Private` as the SOURCE
- `$HOME/Private` as the DESTINATION
- `$HOME/.ecryptfs/Private.sig` for the key signatures.
- `$HOME/.ecryptfs/ALIAS.conf` and for key signature(s) in:
- `$HOME/.ecryptfs/ALIAS.sig`

And if your "user owns both the SOURCE and DESTINATION mount points" and if "the DESTINATION is not already mounted".

If everything looks good, try running `mount.ecryptfs_private` yourself and see what it tells you, the `ecryptfs-setup-private` program could be hiding potentially useful stdout / stderr info.

Or, `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` may be failing somehow.

And just for another check, did you install eCryptfs using CentOS's default package management system? Didn't download random files from the net or a really old/new (possibly incompatible) version or anything?